# Is there a function in r for making a variable that matches a variable and column name?

Tags: r

I want to make a variable that matches the value in a row under a column whose name matches a value in another column's values, but I can't seem to figure out what'll let me do it.

I have this dataset (df):

| var 1 | year1 | year2 | year 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| year1 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| year2 | 23 | 12 | 8 |
| year3 | 12 | 4.4 | 7 |

I am unsure how to do this, have tried and found that this will find the column number of the year column that matches var1 in the first row, but I need it to be a column and I need it to also put in the value in var1 in the new variable. Been stuck for awhile, somewhat new to R.

```
which(colnames(df)==df$var1[1])
```

I want this dataset (df):

| var 1 | year1 | year2 | year 3 | foundyearvar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| year1 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 2 |
| year2 | 23 | 12 | 8 | 12 |
| year3 | 12 | 4.4 | 7 | 7 |

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr (>= v1.1.0):

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(foundyearvar = cur_data()[[var1]], .by = var1)
```

```
   var1 year1 year2 year3 foundyearvar
1 year1     2   4.0     6            2
2 year2    23  12.0     8           12
3 year3    12   4.4     7            7
```

Or, using a split-apply-combine approach in base R:

```r
df |>
  split(df$var1) |>
  lapply(\(x) transform(x, foundyearvar = x[[x$var1]])) |>
  do.call(rbind, args = _)
```

```
   var1 year1 year2 year3 foundyearvar
1 year1     2   4.0     6            2
2 year2    23  12.0     8           12
3 year3    12   4.4     7            7
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can use `sapply`:

```
df$foundyearvar <- sapply(1:nrow(df), 
                          function(x) df[x, df$var1[x]]) # thanks @zephryl
```

Output

```
#  var1 year1 year2 year3 foundyearvar
#1 year1     2   4.0     6            2
#2 year2    23  12.0     8           12
#3 year3    12   4.4     7            7
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use `get`:

```
df %>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(foundyearvar=get(var1))

  var1  year1 year2 year3 foundyearvar
  <chr> <int> <dbl> <int>        <dbl>
1 year1     2   4       6            2
2 year2    23  12       8           12
3 year3    12   4.4     7            7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using base R but first create your data in R, then use the match() function:

```
# create a data frame with 3 columns
df <- structure(
  list(
    var1 = c("year1", "year2", "year3"),
    year1 = c(2, 23, 12),
    year2 = c(4, 12, 4.4),
    year3 = c(6, 8, 7)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -3L)
)


df$foundyearvar <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), match(df$var1, colnames(df)))]
df
   var1 year1 year2 year3 foundyearvar
1 year1     2   4.0     6            2
2 year2    23  12.0     8         12.0
3 year3    12   4.4     7            7
```

Here, the function match() function finds the index of the column in in your data that its name matches the corresponding value in var1.